# Book about a space warrior pilot, augmented with his AI-based spaceship, who crash lands on Earth and meets a girl

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book a while back, then gave it to someone to read, and it was never returned; I have been looking for it ever since. Below is the plotline. If anyone can give me the name of the book and its writer's name, I would be really glad.

Plot Synopsis:
A distant world humanoid space warrior pilot, who has an augmented cerebral connection with his spaceship that is AI-based, crash lands on Earth. He meets the central character, the Girl (I forgot her name). They fall in love and he decide to take her as his bride-to-be. They travel back to his galaxy, where it turns out the pilot is a prince and they stumble into galactic politics.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall any details about the cover?

Comment: I do not remember exactly which year it was published I read this around 2010 and most probably it was published between 1990-2010 (sorry cant narrow it down any more). Just there was a picture of the spaceship (it was very futuristic spaceship unlike our spaceshuttles) as it was used by the elite warriors to wage wars.

Comment: This was sounding a lot like The Cyborg and the Sorcerers by Lawrence Watt Evans until those last two sentences, also the publication dates would be a bit too early. still might be good to know about this one so that if its suggested as an answer you can discount it. Here is a link to a wiki page about it in case you are curious. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cyborg_and_the_Sorcerers

Comment: Sorry, that is not the one I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds vaguely like Catherine Asaro's "Catch the Lightning"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch_the_Lightning

Only vaguely, however. The main male character is linked to his spacecraft, but I don't remember if there was an AI involved. They eventually return to his home, only to find that there's lots of paperwork and different kinds of enemies that go along with a space empire.

Wikipedia says it was published 1997, and the picture it shows shows a futuristic spacecraft for the cover.

Comment: I am so glad you posted that name. Exactly that book. Thanks a million @FinAndTonic for your response. Marking it as "the answer" for this question.